# Return value from PHP parent method when called from child

Tags: php, oop, parent-child, parent

I am new to PHP OOP so I am not sure if I am going about this the right way. The parent method, isRegistered(), will query the db correctly and return a value ($affected_rows) when I call the method from the parent, but will only "echo" the value (will not return it) when I call the method from the child, so I am not sure if I have constructed the child incorrectly. Here is my code:

```
//Log in with social credentials
if(isset($_POST["fb-reg"])) {
$fbOptions = array(
    'email' => "joe@gmail.com",
    'fbId' => "678910",
    'handler' => $handler); //the db connection
    fbRegister($fbOptions);
}

//Instantiate parent and child and get results of query
function fbRegister($fbOptions) {
$a = new newUser();
$fb = new fbUser($fbOptions);
$fb->isRegistered(); // will echo back $affected_rows
$y = isRegistered(); 
    echo $y; // does not return value of $affected_rows
}

//Parent class
class newUser {
public $email;
public $pass;
public $dbconn;
public $confirm;
public $message;

public function __construct($options) {
    $this->email = $options['email'];
    $this->pass = $options['password'];
    $this->confirm = $options['confirm'];
    $this->dbconn = $options['handler'];
    $this->message = array();
    }   
// CHECK IF USER EXISTS ====================================
public function isRegistered() {
$sql=("SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Email = :email");
$query = $this->dbconn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':email' => $this->email));
$affected_rows = $query->rowCount();
return $affected_rows; // query works but does not return value  to calling function
echo $affected_rows;  // query result will be echoed by calling function
    }
}

//Child class
class fbUser extends newUser{
public $id;
public $email;
public $dbconn;         

function __construct($fbOptions) {
    $this->id = $fbOptions['fbId'];
    $this->email = $fbOptions['email'];
    $this->dbconn = $fbOptions['handler'];
     }

public function isRegistered() {
    parent::isRegistered($this->email, $this->dbconn);
         }
}
```

Comment: There is no WAY that your `echo $affected_rows` could EVER be executed, since the `return` terminates the method call right then and there. plus, why is your child `isRegsitered` defined INSIDE the constructor?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: I was missing a curly brace that why it appeared that the child isRegistered is defined in the constructor. Also, the "echo" command is there just to demonstrate that I tried to "echo" the result when I was unable to "return" it - i am not running them concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

I needed a return in the child method:

return parent::isRegistered($this->email, $this->dbconn);